# How to show excluding VAT prices in 'Recently Viewed Products' widget?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, vat

It now only shows the including vat price but I can't find the function to show the excluding vat price. The recently viewed products block is built with knockout.

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html`
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/product/list/columns/final-price.js`

`Catalog prices` and `Display Product Prices In Catalog` are set to **excluding tax** in the backend (all relevant settings are)

How to show excluding vat prices in 'recently viewed products'?